# Highcharts - Scatterplot Marker Hover State lasts too long

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, highcharts

Looking through the HighCharts API to find a way to turn off the hover effect when you un-hover from a marker point.  As it stands currently in my program, HighCharts will actually keep the marker selected even if I move away from the point.  The problem with this approach is sometimes the tooltip that is displayed while hovering will actually block out a point I want to hover on (so I cant hover over said point until the hover effect disappears).

The hover effect only disappears if I move completely out of the graph or I hover over a different marker point.

Anyone have any idea how to achieve this?

---

Edit**
https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/397 apparently this is a bug.

Answer (score 3):

The problem of the tooltop hiding other points is a bug, but from version 2.0 there is an option to stop tooltips from staying open when the mouse has rolled off them:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        stickyTracking: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
}
```

http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#plotOptions-series--stickyTracking says

> When true, the mouseOut event on a series isn't triggered until the
>   mouse moves over another series, or out of the plot area. When false,
>   the mouseOut event on a series is triggered when the mouse leaves the
>   area around the series' graph or markers. This also implies the
>   tooltip. When stickyTracking is false, the tooltip will be hidden when
>   moving the mouse between series. Defaults to true.